# Pendrive cannot boot Error "kernel image not found: vesamenu.c32

Tags: usb-drive

I am trying to boot Ubuntu from a flash drive, but whenever I try and boot it an error comes up and the boot fails.

```
Kernel image not found: vesamenu.c32
```

Comment: which versoin of ubuntu you are trying to install ? Is it 10.10/11.04?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah look first of make sure you are using the correct Version of Ubuntu to make your bootable pendrive. For eg. If you have a 64 bit laptop, it is better you go with 64 bit one.

If you don't know how to check this. Go to your windows computer, type `msconfig` in start and click on msconfig. It will clearly mention if you have a 64 bit or 32 bit system.

Next you can use `unetbootin` to create the bootable usb.

Next important thing is that you check you have a correct boot sequence, i.e your usb is at top then followed by Hard disk. This is important.

Also make sure, you have not connected any other flash drive when u are installing, as it can cause confusion. I think this should suffice your problem. If not don't hesitate to follow up.